# Non-Hardware Device Drivers

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system, kernel

In Windows Internal 7th Edition - Book following text is Mentioned Under Windows Kernel Architecture  
**Device drivers** -This includes both hardware device drivers, which translate user I/O function
calls into specific hardware device I/O requests, and non-hardware device drivers, such as file
system and network drivers.

Can anyone please elaborate on  hardware device drivers and non-hardware device drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have multiple layers - e.g. when a process makes a file IO request it goes to a virtual file system layer, which may send a request to a file system layer, which may send request/s to a software RAID layer, which may send requests to a USB mass storage device driver, which may send a request to a USB controller driver.

You can split these layers into 2 main categories:

a) "device drivers", where there's an actual device. For these, the relationships between device drivers tends to mirror the hierarchical relationships between hardware devices (e.g. "PCI bus with controllers plugged in, with various devices plugged into those controllers, with various peripherals plugged into those devices" may become a tree of "parent device driver communicating with none or more child device drivers that are...").

b) "things that do not drive a device, and therefore are not technically device drivers". For the file IO example above, this is the VFS, file systems and software RAID layer. For networking it'll be code to handle a TCP/IP stack (and figure out routing, etc - which network card should send a packet based on the destination IP address). For user input (keyboard, etc) it could be things like Input Method Editors. For sound it can be code to determine how loud the sound should be on which speakers (on which sound card/s) based on a 2D position.

For most operating systems; device drivers need to be treated as "special" because they need to use interfaces (and possibly direct hardware access) that normal software/processes can't use. For example, for monolithic kernels they might be treated as a kernel extension and (dynamically) linked directly into the kernel.

However; "things that do not drive a device, and therefore are not technically device drivers" end up needing similar special support (e.g. the ability to use the same or similar interfaces that normal software/processes can't use but device drivers can use, the ability to be linked into a monolithic kernel, etc). For an OS designer, the differences between device drivers and "things that aren't technically device drivers but need the same access" is relatively insignificant (compared to normal software/processes which don't have/need special access); so it's tempting to use the same word to describe both - e.g. call them all "kernel modules" (regardless of whether they're device drivers or not); or call them all "device drivers" (regardless of whether they're technically device drivers or not).

Note that there's a few things that confuse this even more:

a) There's actually a third category - "virtual devices". In some cases software is trying to emulate a real device (e.g. RAM disks that use software/RAM to emulate a hard drive; printers that use a PDF file format converter to "print" to a file, etc). For these cases,  emulation/virtualization necessitates implementation as a device driver (but there's technically no device being driven).

b) To make terminology seem more consistent; some operating systems are biased towards defining interfaces as "virtual devices". If you try hard enough you can pretend anything is some kind of abstract virtual device ("It's not a compression/decompression library, it's a virtual compression/decompression device", "It's not a database management engine, it's a virtual relational data storage device", ...).

c) Some operating systems also try to pretend that everything is a file (e.g. Unix - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file ). In this case you might have a directory of "device drivers pretending to be files" (e.g. `/dev`) and end up with "things that are not device drivers that are pretending to be device drivers that are pretending to be files" slapped into the same directory.

Comment: Hey Excellent Response I think I understood the concept ...Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.  If you ask for an example of a non-hardware device driver, an example would be the random number generator device.  On Linux, for example, the "/dev/random" device provides a software implementation of a random number generator so systems without the necessary hardware can still have this function